# Jam and Marmalade setting

Tags: jam

I recently made a batch of marmalade and Ginger Marmalade and although I used the same recipe as I have before, this batch did not set very well at all. I didn't use any extra setting agent. My question is, can I reheat the marmalade and add in some pectin to hopefully set it ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You do want to make sure you have given your marmalade a couple of weeks to set completely before deciding to remake with additional pectin.

In the US, pectin found on grocery store shelves generally contain a sheet with basic recipes, as well as instructions on how to remake your cooked jam/jelly/marmalade if it doesn't set properly.

Here are additional options from [The National Center for Home Food Preservation:](http://nchfp.uga.edu/how/can_07/remake_soft_jelly.html)

> Making Jams and Jellies
>
> Remaking Soft Jellies
>
> Measure jelly to be recooked. Work with no more than 4 to 6 cups at a
>   time.
>
> Please read Using Boiling Water Canners before beginning. If this is
>   your first time canning, it is recommended that you read Principles of
>   Home Canning.
>
> To Remake With Powdered Pectin
>
> For each quart of jelly, mix ¼ cup sugar, ½ cup water, 2 tablespoons
>   bottled lemon juice, and 4 teaspoons powdered pectin. Bring to a boil
>   while stirring. Add jelly and bring to a rolling boil over high heat,
>   stirring constantly. Boil hard ½ minute. Remove from heat, quickly
>   skim foam off jelly, and fill sterile jars, leaving ¼-inch headspace.
>   Adjust new lids and process as recommended in Table 1. For more
>   information on how to sterilize jars see "Sterilization of Empty
>   Jars".
>
> To Remake With Liquid Pectin
>
> For each quart of jelly, measure ¾ cup sugar, 2 tablespoons bottled
>   lemon juice, and 2 tablespoons liquid pectin. Bring jelly only to boil
>   over high heat, while stirring. Remove from heat and quickly add the
>   sugar, lemon juice, and pectin. Bring to a full rolling boil, stirring
>   constantly. Boil hard for 1 minute. Quickly skim off foam and fill
>   sterile jars, leaving ¼-inch headspace. Adjust new lids and process as
>   recommended in Table 1.
>
> To Remake Without Added Pectin
>
> For each quart of jelly, add 2 tablespoons bottled lemon juice. Heat
>   to boiling and boil for 3 to 4 minutes. Use one of the tests described
>   in Testing Jelly without Added Pectin to determine jelly doneness.
>   Remove from heat, quickly skim off foam, and fill sterile jars,
>   leaving ¼-inch headspace. Adjust new lids and process as recommended in Table 1..